# "Could not resolve mscorlib ... .NETFramework,Version=v2.0" in VS2015 from VB6

Tags: vb.net, vb6, windows-forms-designer, vb6-migration, mscorlib

My question is similar to others, but my particular nuance of this problem doesn't appear to have an answer I can find on here so far, so here goes.  (*edits in italics*)

*Our company has a deployed application written in VB6.  Since VB6 development is no longer officially supported in Windows, our company made the decision to port our VB6 application to VB.NET.*

(Prior to this edit, I had mentioned that the project was converted to VB.NET using VS 2015.  This was incorrect, I discovered that my coworker had actually performed the conversion using VS 2008, and I was working on the 2008 project in 2015.)

*So we are now working with the VB.NET conversion in VS2015.  As many of us know, the VS 2008 converter does an incomplete job porting VB6 code to VB.NET code so there are many, many errors to sort through (as of this writing, all compile errors are fixed).*  In particular, though, I'm trying to open the various forms for the project in the Designer so I can see and work with them.  The designer specifically is reporting the error:

```
Could not resolve mscorlib for target framework '.NETFramework,Version=v2.0'. This can happen if the target framework is not installed or if the framework moniker is incorrectly formatted.
```

I saw some mention of a 256 character limit on dependency paths.  This dependency is met in my case.  I have also confirmed that .NET Framework 2.0 is installed and active in my instance of Windows.  I have seen the recommendation to upgrade the .NET Framework version as well, which was successful in itself but did not resolve this `mscorlib` issue.

Full call stack for this error follows:

```
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Design.VsTargetFrameworkUniverse..ctor(IDesignTimeAssemblyLoader assemblyLoader, IVsDesignTimeAssemblyResolution projectAssemblyResolution, IVsSmartOpenScope dispenser)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Design.VsTargetFrameworkUniverse.GetUniverse(IDesignTimeAssemblyLoader assemblyLoader, IVsDesignTimeAssemblyResolution projectAssemblyResolution, IVsSmartOpenScope dispenser)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Design.VsTargetFrameworkProvider..ctor(IVsDesignTimeAssemblyResolution assemblyResolution, IDesignTimeAssemblyLoader assemblyLoader, TypeDescriptionProvider parentProvider, IVsSmartOpenScope openScope)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.VsTargetFrameworkProviderService.get_TargetFrameworkProvider()
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.VsTargetFrameworkProviderService.GetProvider(Type type)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.DesignerSerializationManager.GetType(String typeName)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.DesignerSerializationManager.System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.IDesignerSerializationManager.GetType(String typeName)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.TypeCodeDomSerializer.Deserialize(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, CodeTypeDeclaration declaration)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager manager)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager serializationManager)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.DeferredLoadHandler.Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextManager.Interop.IVsTextBufferDataEvents.OnLoadCompleted(Int32 fReload)
```

How can I gain the ability to view my project in the Designer?

Comment: Others have reported that the following worked for them:
1. Remove and add back project references that have warnings.
2. Rebuild the project
3. Remove and add back Microsoft.Office.Core

Comment: Can you just update to a more recent framework? All the VB6 projects I converted I immediately updated. The conversion tools are very old which is why they use the old framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, opening VB6 files in VB.NET **will not work**. You will have to make modifications in Visual Studio 6.0 or re-write the application in VB.NET/C#.

Older versions of Visual Studio (until 2008) had some converters but they never really worked as expected.

You can take a look at [Visual Basic Tools for Visual Studio](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MatthiasFriedrich.VisualBasicToolsforVisualStudio), it "allows to work with classic VB workspaces and projects within Visual Studio.", this will allow you to modify the VB6 project in a newer version of Visual Studio but **the code will remain VB6**.

Regarding your exact issue, others have reported that the following worked for them:

1. Remove and add back project references that have warnings.
2. Rebuild the project
3. Remove and add back Microsoft.Office.Core

Good luck!

Comment: My coworker used VS2008 to convert the VB6 app to VB.NET, then that project was moved to VS2015.  Unfortunately, as VB6 is no longer supported by MS, we cannot continue to use it at my company.  (More like "fortunately," but it does mean we are stuck with this problem!)  I will look at the VB Tools for VS that you shared, thank you.

Comment: The conversion your coworker did worked correctly afterwards? I suspect the conversion didn't work well and you will have to clean up the VB.NET code it generated. The VB Tools will only help you if you are working with the original VB6 code and from what I have read it still requires you to have the VB6 IDE installed. Maybe not worth wasting your time if you can't continue to use VB6 at your company.

Comment: The conversion never worked.  I have whittled the error count from ~400 down to ~20 and am working on resolving the last few stragglers, among which this is one.  I am in the uncomfortable position that they are requiring me to convert the VB6 to VB.NET and the timeline is too short for a full rewrite.  So I must resolve this.

Comment: Good luck!! Sorry I couldn't help but try posting more of your code, we might see something.

Comment: Thank you.  This is just the designer itself throwing this error, so I'm not sure what code I would post to help pin it down.

Comment: The VS2008 convertor is good enough to get you started, but there is always manual cleanup work required afterwards. It works best if the original VB6 project will compile & run on the machine - meaning all references are good, etc.

Answer (score 0):

As someone who has converted a number of VB6 applications to VB.Net, I always advise a full rewrite.  The languages are just too different. You waste far too much time trying to resolve issues of this type.

Better still, just leave the VB6 application running as is.

[Microsoft's VB6 support statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-basic-6/visual-basic-6-support-policy)

Comment: We need to be able to maintain the application.  The development environment is no longer supported.  Just being able to run the existing deployment will not be enough when fixes or updates need to be made.  Rewriting the entire application from scratch is not feasible on our timeline, as opposed to solving one or two blocking errors, even difficult ones.

Comment: The VB6 programming environment installs and runs fine on Windows 10. Just like it has on every version of Windows since 1998.

Comment: And rewriting from scratch is invariably faster than trying to convert from one language to another.